# ASP.NET MVC AJAX post to controller action not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, asp.net-ajax

In my ASP.NET MVC 4 view, the following is not calling controller action. Click event does get trigger because I can see the alert message. But when I put a breakpoint on the controller action in debug mode, the app does't get to that point and nothing happens when I click 'Ok' on the alert message. I am using LINQ to SQL. Similar calls to save and insert controller actions work fine:

```
$('#DeletePOC').click(function () {
                if (confirm("This action will delete this POC record permanently. Click OK if you want to delete this record; otherwise, click 'Cancel'")) {
                    disableButton(['#CancelPOC', '#POC']);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("POCDelete")', type: "POST", dataType: "json",
                        data: {
                            SitePOCID: $('#POCId').val()
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            $('#POCStatus').html('<div class="success">POC Removed Successfully.</div>');
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            $('#POCStatus').html('<div class="field-validation-error">Some Error Occured in Removing POC.</div>');
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

**Controller**:
I've tested that during debug, app doesn't get to this action method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult POCDelete(int id)
{
   db.POC_dsp(id);
   return Json("");
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should give the data same as the function parameters. In your case, your data name should be id(not SitePocId)

```
$('#DeletePOC').click(function () {
            if (confirm("This action will delete this POC record permanently. Click OK if you want to delete this record; otherwise, click 'Cancel'")) {
                disableButton(['#CancelPOC', '#POC']);
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("POCDelete")', type: "POST", dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        id: $('#POCId').val()
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#POCStatus').html('<div class="success">POC Removed Successfully.</div>');
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        $('#POCStatus').html('<div class="field-validation-error">Some Error Occured in Removing POC.</div>');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks to @Anoop, I came to know that the parameter name in the data should be the same as the parameter name in the action method. This means that the `@Url.Action(ActionMethodName)` would look for the action that has the same parameter name as in the Ajax call. But the error section of my Ajax call above did not display any error. I suppose that has something to do with the class name of the div tag of the error section.